# Ruby on Rails - Active Record FIlter where the value of a referenced table is > 0

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am currently trying to filter out from selected data in Ruby on Rails those where the attribute "amount_available" is greater than zero. This would be no problem via @events.where(ticket_categories.amount_available > 0), but ticket_categories is an array with not a fixed length, because there can be multiple categories. How can you easily iterate through the array in the where clause and do this comparison?

I only need the events in the output where at least one associated category has the amount_available > 0.

This is my code:

```
      @upcoming_events = @events.where("date >=?", Date.current)
      @available_events = @upcoming_events.where(ticket_categories[0].amount_available > 0)
      json_response(@available_events)
```

Comment: Does the column have the array data type or is it a representation of array? What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain `where` conditions and you can add conditions that are based on associated models with `joins`:

```
  available_events = @events
    .where('date >= ?', Date.current)
    .joins(:ticket_categories).where('ticket_categories.amount > 0')
    .group(:id)

  render json: available_events
```

Note: Database joins might return duplicate records (depending on your database structure and the condition) therefore the need to `group` the result set by `id`.

Answer (score -1):

It is only a representation because the Events table is linked to TicketCategories via has_many. I use PostgresSQL and could now solve it with the following code:

```
      @upcoming_events = @close_events.where("date >=?", Date.current)
      available_events = []
      @upcoming_events.each do |event|
          
          event.ticket_categories.each do|category|
              if category.amount_available > 0
                  available_events.push(event)
                  break;
              end
          end
        
      end
      render json: available_events
```

Comment: Please note that this answer leads to N+1 queries. Imagine you have 100 upcoming events. Then you would trigger 100 additional database queries while running `category.amount_available` when iterating `event.ticket_categories.each`.